# Is it ever unsafe to commit an SQL Connection object?

Tags: java, sql, database, connection, database-connection

I am getting the error:

```
SQL State:  25001
Error Code: 20000
Message:    Cannot close a connection while a transaction is still active.
```

I understand this because I am closing the db connection, when a transaction is not committed or rolled-back.

This should be fairly easy to fix.  However, I am using a connection pool.  So I am really not sure where this connection is being left uncommitted.  I am just trying to gracefully close each connection in the connection pool.

Is it safe to just always call commit before closing the transaction?

```
if (!connection.isClosed())
{
    connection.commit();
    connection.close();
}
```

The other way to fix this is to carefully check each database action to assure the connection is committed.  Is this a safe shortcut?

Comment: **Define** safe? `DELETE FROM USERS; commit;`

Comment: @Elliott Frisch I am assuming all the actions are intended.  However, there could have been an exception that caused the commit to never happen.  I am not 100% why the commit never happened.

Comment: I'd be more comfortable blindly rolling back, over blindly committing.

Comment: What is you rolled back the last database update.  Adding a user, for example.

Comment: And it threw an Exception; so that *presumably* didn't work properly

Answer (score 1):

Log it and rollback.

Never blindly commit.

The connection pool should rollback any connection that is returned with an active transaction. The thinking here is that the reason the transaction is still active when the connection is being returned is that the borrowing thread had some sort of problem and didn't finish its process normally.

Comment: Isn't there a chance I will rollback a useful transaction?

Comment: Never. If it was a useful transaction, then it would have been committed. By definition, any business logic that omits the commit has at least one bug (mishandling transaction boundaries) and therefore is completely suspect because it was not properly tested/validated. If you rollback, you will protect the integrity of your database and find bugs sooner. If you commit, you will get bad data in your database and hide insidious bugs.